# Powershell Active Directory is user a member of security group display yes or no

Tags: powershell

I looking for PowerShell script to display that yes or no if user is member of security group

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are looking for then this should work.

```
$users = @('user1','user2')
$securityGroupMembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'Domain Users'

foreach($user in $users){
    if($user -in $securityGroupMembers.Name){
        "$User is a member"
    }else{
        "$user is not a member"
    }
}
```

Comment: You spent way more time and effort than the OP did..